# jetbrains.exodus.ExodusException: Unsupported Comparable value type

Tags: java, xodus

When trying to persist a `ComparableSet` with a custom Comparable type, [LocalDayTimeRange](https://gist.github.com/cyberquarks/8b7a56870eb92ee3bfad8b55a823730d/raw/1104f04c116a5047382bc9809b3acce3783d6c7a/LocalDayTimeRange.java):

```java
ComparableSet<LocalDayTimeRange> timeRanges = new ComparableSet<>();
LocalDayTimeRange sundayRange = new LocalDayTimeRange(
     LocalDayTimeRange.DAY.SUNDAY,
     LocalTime.parse("01:00"),
     LocalTime.parse("23:00"));
LocalDayTimeRange mondayRange = new LocalDayTimeRange(
     LocalDayTimeRange.DAY.MONDAY,
     LocalTime.parse("07:00"),
     LocalTime.parse("08:00"));
```

It throws this error:

```
jetbrains.exodus.ExodusException: Unsupported Comparable value type: class com.myapp.properties.LocalDayTimeRange

    at jetbrains.exodus.bindings.ComparableValueType.getPredefinedType(ComparableValueType.java:91)
    at jetbrains.exodus.bindings.ComparableSetBinding.writeObject(ComparableSetBinding.java:59)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.tables.PropertyTypes.writePropertyValue(PropertyTypes.java:120)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.tables.PropertyTypes.propertyValueToEntry(PropertyTypes.java:109)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStoreImpl.setProperty(PersistentEntityStoreImpl.java:868)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntity.setProperty(PersistentEntity.java:120)
```

Whereas, it is registered:

```java
entityStore.executeInTransaction(txn -> {
    ((PersistentEntityStore) txn.getStore()).registerCustomPropertyType(
        txn, LocalDayTimeRange.class, LocalDayTimeRangeBinding.BINDING);
})
```

What could be wrong in my setup?

Comment: Also, when saving the custom Comparable, `LocalDayTimeRange` not inside a `ComparableSet` it works, so I assume the issue is with the `ComparableSet`

Comment: Thanks for reporting https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-833.

Comment: @vyacheslav-lukianov no problem, I've been digging the codes seeing where the problem is rooted from what I see the ComparableSet was configured to accept only predefined types. Looking at the code it seems because of resolving Class into actual binding which was put into an array for lookup, not sure why, maybe the type id of the class and the binding is not inherently accessible from that specific location. So maybe if the bindings can be retrieved from that part maybe there's no need to have to predefined the acceptable types